# Linq. How to query list within list?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have Store List (storeList) object. (Consists of list of Stores)
Each Store has list of Addresses. Each address have AddressType property that can be PHYSICAL, ALTERNATIVE or MAILING.

I am trying to return PHYSICAL Address object so I can modify its properties:

This is my first attempt:

```
StoreAddressList result = 
    (from str in storeList
     where
     str.AssetAddresses.Any(p => p.AddressType.Name == "PHYSICAL")
     select str.AssetAddresses).FirstOrDefault();
```

As a result I expect to get list with only one item (where address type is PHYSICAL), but I get list with 3 items (with all three types). What's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to select? It looks like you're trying to select the first store in the list where any of its address types is equal to "PHYSICAL". Is that correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flatten the list of list of addresses by projecting each store to its list of addresses, use `SelectMany` to achieve the flattening, and then take only those where the address type is physical:

```
var addressesToModify = 
    storeList.SelectMany(store => store.AssetAddresses)
             .Where(address => address.AddressType.Name == "PHYSICAL");
```

In query syntax:

```
var addressesToModify =
    from store in storeList
    from address in store.AssetAddresses
    where address.AddressType.Name == "PHYSICAL"
    select address;
```

Notice how it reads exactly like we described. From each `store` in the `storeList`, from each `address` in `store.AssetAddresses` where `address` is a physical address, select `address`.

Now iterate the results of the query and modify as needed.

Also, I strongly suggest making an enum

```
public enum AddressType { Physical, Alternative, Mailing }
```

and changing `Address.AddressType` to be of this type

```
public AddressType AddressType { get; }
```

and then you can write

```
where address.AddressType == AddressType.Physical
```

or

```
.Where(address => address.AddressType == AddressType.Physical);
```

Comment: :-). You are fast. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `SelectMany` to flattern out the list of addresses.

```
var result =
  storeList
  .SelectMany(store => store.AssetAddress)
  .Where(address => address.AddressType == "PHYSICAL")
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm guessing there will also be a `where` on the storeList so that you only get the address of the store you're interested in.